# Merge lines with similar ID and sum corresponding values

Tags: perl, awk

I would like to combine similar lines to create a unique output matrix that sums the counts after the `-` sign. Please see my example below:

```
278-3192 NC_002188.1
310-2831 NC_007653.1
384-2206 NC_004068.1
1059-573 NC_004068.1
```

output

```
NC_002188.1 3192
NC_007653.1 2831
NC_004068.1 2779
```

Comment: When you say "similar" I presume you mean "identical"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use awk's associative array:

```
awk '{split($1,a, "-"); arr[$2]+=a[2]} END{for(i in arr) print i, arr[i]}' file
```

Answer (score 2):

If the records are already sorted by NC_xxxx numbers, you can do it without array *(you can also sort the file before using `sort`)*:

```
awk -F'[- ]' 'o!=$3{print o,s;o=$3;s=$2;next}{s+=$2}END{print o,s}' file
```